# How to conditionally hide a section base on current user's group membership in workshop?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I tried to use the workaround where we simulate it with a headerless collapsable section, using a variable to control the collapse state.

However it seems that there is no way to make a variable based on user's properties such as group membership, userid, etc.

Ideally I would reference the validity of the action parameters to reuse the permission there.

Is there any way to implement this currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a string array variable in Workshop, you can initialize it to Multipass attributes such as group membership:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAtIt.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUhlm.png

Section visibility is controlled by boolean variables, so you then you want to pass this string array into a Function, evaluate the groups as needed within the Function, and then return a boolean variable that will control the visibility of your section as needed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3uq7.png